# How can i find part of the string in url address with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good evening, I have a problem to find string from url address when I click on next page, for example I have url: http://www.example.cz/example/example-example/page/2/  <- hyphen is optinal. I need to find part http://www.example.cz/example/example-example/ <- without part page/number/ and save it to variable. Can you guys help me how to do it ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4H8dy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on `/` and then reform the string.

For example (this assumes `http://` is part of the string):

```
"http://www.example.cz/example/example-example/page/2/".split("/").slice(0,5).join("/")
```

1. Split on `/`
2. Slice out the first 5 items in the array.
3. Re-join them together with a `/`

Results: `"http://www.example.cz/example/example-example"`

Comment: @user3276426 Yes, that property includes protocol as well.

Answer (score 0):

If page is always in the url and also what needs to be removed, you can simply split on 'page' and take the first element of the resulting array.

```
var url = "http://www.example.cz/example/example-example/page/2/",
    urlParsed = url.split("page")[0];
```